# Need Python to reindex Elasticsearch index

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I need python to reindex indices in Elasticsarch.
But on the "es.reindex(...)" I get an error
"TypeError: Positional arguments can't be used with Elasticsearch API methods. Instead only use keyword arguments."

How to fix this?

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

nodes = ['http://localhost:9200/']
es = Elasticsearch(nodes)
print(es.info().body)

indexPrefix = "test-index"

res = es.indices.get(
    index=f"{indexPrefix}*"
)
indices = []
for index in res:
    indices.append(index)

no_of_indices = len(indices)
print(indices, no_of_indices)

for source_index in indices:
    destination_index = "test-neu-2"
    result = es.reindex({
        "source": {"index": source_index},
        "dest": {"index": destination_index}
    }, wait_for_completion=True)

    print (result)
```

Tried to use internetsearch but could not find a solution how to fix the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as reported by your error message, positional arguments

```
es.reindex({ "source": {"index": source_index}, "dest": {"index": destination_index}}, wait_for_completion=True)
```

are not allowed. You're missing the keyword argument `body`:

```
for source_index in indices:
    destination_index = "test-neu-2"
    result = es.reindex(
        body={
            "source": {"index": source_index},
            "dest": {"index": destination_index}
        },
        wait_for_completion=True)
```